# /title command displaying literal JSON instead of proper title

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying the title command but it just would not work! I typed in `/title @a title Flower Shop` and it worked by showing "Flower Shop" in the middle of the screen, but when I try this: `/title @a title Flower Shop {"color":"dark_red"}` it just adds the literal text `{"color":dark_red"}` to "Flower Shop" instead of changing the color!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to define the colour of a title in Minecraft, you will need to include both the text and the colour inside of the curly braces.

In your case, the command would look like:

```
/title @a title {"text":"Flower Shop","color":"dark_red"}
```

In this command, `"text"` is used to define the title shown on the screen, and `"color"` defines the colour of the text.

The same command will work to define a subtitle if you change `/title @a title` to `/title @a subtitle`, but you will need to run the subtitle command **before** the title command, as they will appear together.